# Javascript Empty select

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, select, populate

I have a `<select>` populated from an array with code:

```
<select id="selector" name="selector"</select>
<button type=button onclick=populateSelect(states)>Click me1!</button>
<button type=button onclick=populateSelect(states2)>Click me2!</button>
...
var states = {
    "Select State": "",
    "Alabama": "AL",
    "Alaska": "AK",
    "Arizona": "AZ",
    "Arkansas": "AR"
}
var states2 = {
    "Select State": "",
    "Alabama2": "AL2",
    "Alaska2": "AK2",
    "Arizona2": "AZ2",
    "Arkansas2": "AR2"
}
function populateSelect(array) {
var vl, txt;
    for (txt in array) {
        vl = array[txt]
        $('<option/>').val(vl).text(txt).appendTo($('#selector'))
        }
}
```

so it's content depends on what button I click. But `.appendTo()` adds data to the end of the drop-down list, so it's not replaced. I want to erase `<select>` content before adding new data.

How can  I do so?

Comment: You can add an `if` statement before you append to the `selector` that will check if it is populated ( you can see if the string `<option/>` exists) and then you can iterate over the `option` tags and use the `remove()` function to remove each option before adding the new ones.

Comment: Inlinde HTML (and other code) should be between backquotes, otherwise it is interpreted as mark-up by this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just explicitly empty the selector before appending:

```
$("#selector").empty();

for (txt in array) {
    vl = array[txt];
    $('<option/>').val(vl).text(txt).appendTo($('#selector'));
}
```

Comment: It worked, but now the droplist looks:
"empty selected string"
"content of states/states2"
But I need that the first element was from the states array
Or a custom string will work as well

Comment: @grekkon I don't understand your comment, and now I think I don't understand what " I want to erase content before adding new data" means. *edit* never mind I see what you mean.

Comment: I worked perfectly!
I should have tried harder to do it myself
Thank you!

Comment: @grekkon no I apologize; I didn't look at your code carefully enough :)